# How to add object with default member into Scripting.Dictionary as object reference, not as default member value?

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary, autodesk-inventor

*This VBA problem also maybe applies to Microsoft Office although I experience it with [autodesk-inventor](/questions/tagged/autodesk-inventor) object `Inventor.Sheet`. So do not hesitate to answer also with VBA+Office experience.*

Initialized `Inventor.Sheet` can be used as:

```
Debug.Print oSheet.TitleBlock.Name ' prints "Title Block 1"
```

and also as

```
Debug.Print oSheet ' prints 11234869 long integer, value of default member
```

This dualistic behavior is caused by default property of the object.

The problem is that whenever I use

```
Dim TitleBlocksLargestSheet As Scripting.Dictionary
TitleBlocksLargestSheet.Add oTitleBlock, oSheet
```

then adding into dictionary inserts long integer value instead of object reference to `oSheet`.

**How object reference can be inserted into the dictionary?**

I suspect that dictionary `Add` method prefers `=` operation before of `Set` operation when both are possible.

So in the following examples I always end up with integers in dictionary items instead of objects:

```vb
'*** get a dictionary of used title blocks (corner stamps) with largest sheet size for each
For Each oSheet In oDrawingDocument.Sheets

    '** get title block of active sheet
    Dim oTitleBlock As Inventor.TitleBlock
    Set oTitleBlock = oSheet.TitleBlock

    If Not oTitleBlock Is Nothing Then
        '** add or update title block usage
        If Not TitleBlocksLargestSheet.Exists(oTitleBlock) Then
            TitleBlocksLargestSheet.Add oTitleBlock, cobj(oSheet)
        Else
            Dim oLargestSheetSeen As Inventor.Sheet
            Set oLargestSheetSeen = TitleBlocksLargestSheet(oTitleBlock)
            If oSheet.Width * oSheet.Height > oLargestSheetSeen.Width * oLargestSheetSeen.Height Then
                TitleBlocksLargestSheet.Item(oTitleBlock) = oSheet
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next oSheet

-- *** usage - retrieval from the dictionary
For Each oSheet In TitleBlocksLargestSheet.Items 'ERROR 424: Object required.
    Set oTitleBlock = oSheet.TitleBlock
    '...some other code
Next oSheet
```

---

UPDATE:

```vb
Debug.Print TypeName(TitleBlocksLargestSheet.Item(oTitleBlock))
IRxSheet ' perhaps there's no problem with storage but with retrieval?
Debug.Print VarType(TitleBlocksLargestSheet.Item(oTitleBlock))
3  ' (Long Integer)
```

Comment: I don't have Autodesk, so I checked on Excel by adding Combobox (that have a default "Value" property) to a dictionnary, and I didn't get problems retrieving the combobox ref. I didn't cast the combobox with Cobj. Could you add the line `Debug.Print TypeName(TitleBlocksLargestSheet(oTitleBlock))` after your Add to check the type of the data stored?

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question as well as code sample (see comment in code where error is thrown). By `TypeName()`, it seems that object is stored although `VarType()` reports `Long Integer`. Perhaps there is no problem on storage, but on retrieval (in `For Each`). Could you please try that retrieval in Excel?

Comment: Vartype(Object) always returns the type of the default property, so you cannot use it here to check the type of the object stored. (cf [VarType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278470(v=office.15).aspx) )

Comment: BTW, `Dictionary.Items()` is a method that returns an array of variant, you cannot iterate with `For Each oSheet` if `oSheet` is not a `Variant`.

Comment: It makes perfect sense. I changed `For Each` to `For ... Next` and it works. If you add an answer, I'll accept it. Strange this is that I cannot find any data type specification in [Dictionary documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4(v=vs.84).aspx). That added to my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dictionary.Items()` is a [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4(v=vs.84).aspx) returning an `Array of Variant` [*]. You can iterate through with `For Each ...` only if the iterating variable is also a `Variant`, or you can use a `For ... To ...` structure.

```
Dim oSheet as Inventor.Sheet
Dim vSheet as Variant
Dim iSheet as long
'Use this way
For Each vSheet In TitleBlocksLargestSheet.Items
    Set oSheet = vSheet ' you may want to check that vSheet is really a Sheet before
    Set oTitleBlock = oSheet.TitleBlock
    '...some other code
Next vSheet
'or this one
For iSheet = 0 to TitleBlocksLargestSheet.Count - 1
    Set oSheet = TitleBlocksLargestSheet.Item(iSheet)
    Set oTitleBlock = oSheet.TitleBlock
    '...some other code
Next iSheet
```

[*] You can check this with `Debug.Print TypeName(TitleBlocksLargestSheet.Items)` which prints `Variant()`